# Unexpected trace trap

Tags: c, macos

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_FIL 15
#define MAX_COL 15
#define MAX 15*15


int frase_a_taula(char frase[], char taula[MAX_FIL][MAX_COL]) {
    int i, j, k = 0, l, res = 0, final = 0;
    for (i = 0; !final; i++) {
        l = 0;
        for (j = i; frase[j] != ' ' && frase[j] != '.'; j++) {
            taula[k][l] = frase[j];
            l++;
        }
        taula[k][l] = '\0';
        if (frase[j] == '.') final = 1;
        i = j;
        k++;
        res++;
    }
    return res;
}


void mescla_string_taula(char taula[MAX_FIL][MAX_COL], int n_filas, int coeficient) {
    int n_mescles = 0, i, ind1, ind2;
    if (coeficient == 2) {
        n_mescles = n_filas / 2;
    }
    else if (coeficient == 1) {
        n_mescles = n_filas / 4;
    }

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < n_mescles; i++) {
        ind1 = rand() % n_filas;
        ind2 = rand() % n_filas;
        char *temp = (char *)malloc((strlen(taula[ind1]) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(temp, taula[ind1]);
        strcpy(taula[ind1], taula[ind2]);
        strcpy(taula[ind2], temp);
        free(temp);
    }

}

void alenteix_i_mescla_frase(char frase[MAX], char frase_lenta[MAX], 
                             int velocitat, int coeficient) {
    char taula[MAX_FIL][MAX_COL];
    int i, j, len_frase_lenta;
    int n_paraules = frase_a_taula(frase, taula);
    mescla_string_taula(taula, n_paraules, coeficient);

    
    strcpy(frase_lenta, taula[0]);

    len_frase_lenta = strlen(frase_lenta);
    for (i = 1; i < n_paraules; i++) {
        if (velocitat == 1) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                frase_lenta[len_frase_lenta] = '.';
                frase_lenta[len_frase_lenta + 1] = '.';
                frase_lenta[len_frase_lenta + 2] = '.';
                len_frase_lenta += 3;
                for (j = 0; j < strlen(taula[i]); j++) {
                    frase_lenta[len_frase_lenta] = taula[i][j];
                    len_frase_lenta++;
                }
            }
            else {
                frase_lenta[len_frase_lenta] = ' ';
                len_frase_lenta++;
                for (j = 0; j < strlen(taula[i]); j++) {
                    frase_lenta[len_frase_lenta] = taula[i][j];
                    len_frase_lenta++;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (velocitat == 2) {
            frase_lenta[len_frase_lenta] = '.';
            frase_lenta[len_frase_lenta + 1] = '.';
            frase_lenta[len_frase_lenta + 2] = '.';
            len_frase_lenta += 3;
            for (j = 0; j < strlen(taula[i]); j++) {
                frase_lenta[len_frase_lenta] = taula[i][j];
                len_frase_lenta++;
            }
        }
    }
    frase_lenta[len_frase_lenta] = '.';
    frase_lenta[len_frase_lenta+1] = '\0';
    
}


int main() {
    printf("Introdueix nom del fitxer: ");
    char path[MAX];
    scanf("%s", path);
    printf("Introdueix velocitat de parla: ");
    int velocitat;
    scanf("%d", &velocitat);
    printf("Introdueix el coeficient de yodificacio: ");
    int coef;
    scanf("%d", &coef);
    FILE* f = fopen(path, "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("Fitxer no trobat!");
    }
    else {
        char line[MAX], frase_yodificada[MAX];
        while (fgets(line, MAX, f) != NULL) {
            alenteix_i_mescla_frase(line, frase_yodificada, velocitat, coef);
            printf("%s\n", frase_yodificada);
        }
        printf("De processar...ha acabat, el fitxer\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the file `yodatest.txt`

```
may the force be with you.
may the force be with you every day of your life.
avui fa un dia molt bonic.
hola.
si entrenes molt i ets perseverant arribaras lluny i tindras molts poders.
un dia em comprare una moto i anire volant fins a l'estrella de la mort.
no hi ha dia que no m'agradi mirar les estrelles de nit.
```

When compiling and executing this code in `Ubuntu wsl` under `Windows`, I get no error whatsoever. However, when I compile the code and execute it in `MacOs`, I get the output:

`[1]    60023 trace trap  ./main.exe`

Sometimes it executes correctly, sometimes it doesn't, but I tried executing it under `Ubuntu` several times and I always got the correct answer.
Also, commenting `mescla_string_taula` seems to work, but again, I can't be sure due the nature of the error. Basically, that function just shuffles the matrix.
Any clue on why is this happening?

A correct example would be:

```
Introdueix nom del fitxer: yodatest.txt
Introdueix velocitat de parla: 1
Introdueix el coeficient de yodificacio: 1
may the...force you...with be.
with the...force be...may of...every day...you your...life.
avui fa...un bonic...molt dia.
hola.
si molts...molt i...ets poders...arribaras lluny...i perseverant...entrenes tindras.
volant anire...em comprare...una fins...i dia...un moto...a l'estrella...de la...mort.
no de...ha dia...que nit...m'agradi mirar...les no...hi estrelles.
De processar...ha acabat, el fitxer
```

Comment: You probably have some bug leading to undefined behavior (likely out of bounds access somewhere). Either reduce it to [mcve] or use debugger to inspect the program.

Comment: Please explain the line: `i = j;` in routine `frase_a_taula`

Comment: @stark `frase_a_taula` should take a string with spaces, always ending in '.', and put each word splitted in a different row. So in that line I'm copying the actual char in an empty row if it is not a space or '.'. If so, it needs to be in a new row.

Comment: new row is k++.  Why do you have two variables i and j which are always set equal to each other?

Comment: @stark you're right

Comment: In C, you are responsible for your own bounds checking. Check _every_ array index against its maximum before dereferencing it, unless it is _proven_ to be within safe range. In this program, I see potential problems with word length (14 is max, 15 is a buffer overrun) and with total output length (padding with `...` causes output to grow beyond input size).

Comment: valgrind is your friend

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to start by showing how I used a debugger to find the problem, because this is a technique that's not as well known as it should be.

First I copy-and-pasted the provided source code into a file `yoda.c`, and the provided test input into a file `yodatest.txt`.  (As an aside for any bystanders reading this: this is why we always ask that source code and test data be provided as text, in the question, not as images or anything.  It takes just seconds to copy and paste things out of my web browser, into my C compilation environment, and then I'm off and running.)

I compiled `yoda.c` and ran it, and got a very similar error:

```
Abort trap: 6
```

This was quite promising.  (Sometimes it's difficult or impossible to reproduce a bug, making it orders of magnitude more difficult to diagnose.)

Next I compiled for debugging:

```
cc -g yoda.c
```

and ran the program under the debugger:

```
$ lldb a.out
(lldb) target create "a.out"
Current executable set to 'a.out' (x86_64).
(lldb) run
```

Typing "run" runs the program.  But now, when it crashes, I get a fair amount more output from the debugger:

```
2022-01-18 19:21:07.871139-0500 a.out[34597:99984533] detected source and destination buffer overlap
Process 34597 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x00007fff57022e3e libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
->  0x7fff57022e3e <+10>: jae    0x7fff57022e48            ; <+20>
    0x7fff57022e40 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x7fff57022e43 <+15>: jmp    0x7fff5701a0b8            ; cerror_nocancel
    0x7fff57022e48 <+20>: retq   
Target 0: (a.out) stopped.
```

I can type "bt" to get a stack backtrace:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff57022e3e libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fff57161150 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 333
    frame #2: 0x00007fff56f7f312 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 127
    frame #3: 0x00007fff56f7f485 libsystem_c.dylib`abort_report_np + 177
    frame #4: 0x00007fff56fa3c2d libsystem_c.dylib`__chk_fail + 48
    frame #5: 0x00007fff56fa3c3d libsystem_c.dylib`__chk_fail_overlap + 16
    frame #6: 0x00007fff56fa3c6e libsystem_c.dylib`__chk_overlap + 49
    frame #7: 0x00007fff56fa3e39 libsystem_c.dylib`__strcpy_chk + 64
    frame #8: 0x000000010000084e a.out`mescla_string_taula(taula=0x00007ffeefbff550, n_filas=12, coeficient=1) at yoda.c:44
    frame #9: 0x0000000100000907 a.out`alenteix_i_mescla_frase(frase="si entrenes molt i ets perseverant arribaras lluny i tindras molts poders.\n", frase_lenta="hola.", velocitat=1, coeficient=1) at yoda.c:56
    frame #10: 0x0000000100000dd2 a.out`main at yoda.c:117
    frame #11: 0x00007fff56ed3115 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

This tells me that the offending call to `strcpy` was the one on line 44 of `yoda.c`.  (That's handy, because there are four calls to `strcpy` in the program, and otherwise I might not know which one caused the problem.)

Evidently the line

```
strcpy(taula[ind1], taula[ind2]);
```

in `mescla_string_taula()` can copy a string on top of itself.  `strcpy` is not defined to behave properly in that situation.

One function that *is* defined to work properly in case of overlap is `memmove`.  I replaced the offending line with

```
memmove(taula[ind1], taula[ind2], strlen(taula[ind2])+1);
```

and now the program seems to work.

Please note that I have not analyzed the problem more deeply, or checked for other problems, let alone proved the program correct for all inputs.  (In a comment, Ruud Helderman had identified some other suspicious code.)  But on my machine the modified program does now generate the desired output for that one test case.